# django models return of custom method seems to be cached

Tags: django, django-models

I have written model containing some nutritions data, it contains some custom arrays and methods. I have problem with one of the custom methods, which is adding a value in every request, starting not from beginning but from return of previous request. It sounds confusing but I hope below code will clarify everything:

```
class Article(models.Model):   
    protein = models.FloatField()
    carbohydrates = models.FloatField()
    fat = models.FloatField()

    def add_value(self, list):
        for i, x in enumerate(list[:]):
            value = getattr(self, x['field'])                
            list[i]['value'] = x['initial'] + value # this line adds value in every request, so if value=2, for protein browser will show 3, 5, 7 ... adding 2 after every page reload
        return list

    _basic_ingredients = [
        {'field': 'protein', 'initial': 1},
        {'field': 'carbohydrates', 'initial': 2},
        {'field': 'fat', 'initial': 3},
    ]

    def get_basic_ingredients(self):
        return self.add_value(self._basic_ingredients)

views.py
def article_page(request, id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)
    return render(request, 'app/template.html', {'article': article})

template.html
{% for row in article.get_basic_ingredients %}
    <p>{{ row.field }}: {{ row.value }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried changing list name, added enumerate, list copy with [:], nothing helps. I am probably missing something, but cannot find what exactly. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you post the code for the View as well?

Comment: added as requested in primary message

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem you are trying to solve, or the feature you want to implement.

Comment: What's being displayed in the rendered template? Also, you should try to avoid overriding built-in names such as ```list```.

Comment: Above is only an example, in fact this function calculates daily % of required consumption, I have vitamins, different fat acids etc, which have different requirements, as well as different units. It is lots of data, so I just wanted to have 1 big array of data in a model, I dont want to do any calculations in views or templates, I dont want to remember if calcium is measured with g or mg either:)

Comment: I forgot about the list when I translated my code so it is understandable in English, thanks:) Provided that user loads article with protein, carbohydrates, fat all equal to 10, template would render: protein: 11 carbohydrates: 12 fat: 13, after next request protein: 21 carbohydrates: 22 fat: 23 etc, I believe it must be some problems in my for loop in model method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really can't understand what you are trying to achieve here, so I can't tell you how to solve your problem. Identifying the problem, though, is simple: `_basic_ingredients` is a class-level variable, so will be shared by all members of the Article model, and will persist across requests until the process is killed or restarted.

Comment: Regarding what I want to achieve is making easier for me rendering data in template, like label, recommended amount to eat daily, unit. I have around 100 variables so what i want is looping over array in my template, which will make code easier to mantain. Re _basic_ingredients variable, it is static anyway so it shouldnt cause an issue, it should remain the same for all requests, add_value() method just adds the same value for static dictionary, so I still dont get why it doesnt work. I am not sure it is error in my loop or this is just how django models work.

Comment: But why are you trying to do that via a class variable on the Article model? I just can't grasp what you are intending to happen.

Comment: Do you have recomendation where this array with data could be transfered too? I put it in model as in can be reusable, as well as it have access to self.field values

Comment: To put it in 1 sentence, what I need is array of data which can be reusable both in views and in templates, containing several additional information for most of model fields, like unit, recommended daily intake, allowing me to input additional data to this array later in views. For example: in 1 view I would like to calculate daily % of intake for every ingredient for 100g of an article, so I will need to divide value of model instance field's by value of array containing daily recomendation. After that I would need to add results of this calculation to array with data to use it  in template

Comment: I just transfered my data array from model to view. I also added similar function similar to def add_value form model class, problem still persist. So this is not model related issue, but rather my loop.

Comment: Ok, finally I solved my problem. I didnt understand that by slicing array or assigning it to another array I made something called soft copy. After using deepcopy from copy module everything works as it should.